# JSON Deserialization and Cyclic dependencies

Tags: json, rest, jersey, jackson, gson

My below JSON is not getting de-serialized when I posted through Jersey Rest Service. When googled I found that there is a cyclic dependency which causes this issue.

Can you please let me know how to resolve this issue.

```
{
"asset":{
    "id":"123456",
    "price":"12.9",
    "quantity":"1",
    "asset":[
        {
            "id":"907",
            "price":"123"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my Java Class Used for Mapping and Posting Data for WS.

```
 public class Asset {

 private String id;
 private String price;
 private String quantity;
 private List<NestedAssset> asset = new ArrayList<NestedAsset>();
  -  --
 getters and setters follows
 }


 public class NestedAsset{
    private String id;
    private String price;
    -  --
    getters and setters follows
 }
```

When this json is mapped to these pojo and sent for POST request, looks like consuming service is unable to deserialize these object

Comment: There should be no comma after "123"

Comment: There are quite a few details missing here.

Comment: Definitions above do not show any cyclic dependency yet, unless `Asset` and `NestedAsset` are related. Are they? (`NestedAsset extends Asset` or such)

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the `@JsonIdentity` annotation for Jackson to resolve cyclical dependencies:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="childId", scope = Child.class)
```

Sample application:

```
public class CyclicalDependencyMain {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(generateParent());
        System.out.println(json);

        Parent parent = objectMapper.readValue(json, Parent.class);
        System.out.println(parent);

    }

    public static Parent generateParent() {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        Child child = new Child();

        child.setChildId(1);
        child.setParent(parent);

        parent.setParentId(1);
        parent.setChild(child);

        return parent;
    }
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="parentId", scope = Parent.class)
class Parent {
    private int parentId;
    private Child child;

    public int getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(int parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public Child getChild() {
        return child;
    }

    public void setChild(Child child) {
        this.child = child;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Parent{" +
                "parentId=" + parentId +
                ", child=" + child +
                '}';
    }
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="childId", scope = Child.class)
class Child {
    private int childId;
    private Parent parent;

    public int getChildId() {
        return childId;
    }

    public void setChildId(int childId) {
        this.childId = childId;
    }

    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Child{" +
                "childId=" + childId +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"parentId":1,"child":{"childId":1,"parent":1}}
Parent{parentId=1, child=Child{childId=1}}
```

**Update** Solution based on `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`

```
class Parent {
    private int parentId;
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Child child;
    // getters/setters and everything else
}

class Child {
    private int childId;
    @JsonBackReference
    private Parent parent;
    // getters/setters and everything else
}
```

This approach works as well if you work with Parent class as a top class all the time. That approach would not work if you wouldtry to serialize and/or deserialize `Child` as a top class.

Comment: So how does jsonbackreference and jsonbackreference implies to this scenario

Comment: @skanda there is one limitation of using JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference. I've added an example to the solution with details.

Answer (score 0):

Use @JsonIgnore instead of @XmlTransient to break the circular dependency.

Comment: When I use @JsonIgnore the child asset item is not getting deserialized and hence i am unable to get its value